# Javascript- How to add boundaries on the perimeter of the game canvas?

Tags: javascript

See, the problem is that the game piece can fly out off the canvas, and its a huge advantage for them to beat the game. The whole point of this game is to avoid the oncoming game obstacles, but if they fly out of the canvas, they can avoid the oncoming obstacles, and they can survive forever. Can i add a boundary to kill them if they touch the outer rim of the game canvas?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
<style>
canvas {
    border:7px solid #00aaff;
    background-color: #00aaff;
}
</style>
</head>

<body onload="startGame()">
<br>

<button onmousedown="accelerate(-0.2)"onmouseup="accelerate(0.05)"<p style="height:27px;width:815px">Click to Accelerate</button>
<div class="resetButton"></div>
<button <p style="height:27px;width:815px"<type="button"onclick="alert('Owner: Landon Sturtevant')">Credits</button>
<button <p style="height:27px;width:815px"<type="button"onclick="alert('Click OK to Continue')">Pause</button>
<button <p style="height:27px;width:815px"<type="button"onclick="alert('High Score is ' + highScore());">HighScore</button>
<script>
function highScore(score) {
   var saved = 0;
   try { saved = parseFloat(localStorage.highScore); } catch (e) { saved = 0; }
   if (!(typeof score === 'undefined')) {
      saved = score;
      localStorage.highScore = '' + score;
   }
   if (isNaN(saved)) {
      saved = 0;
      localStorage.highScore = '0';
   }
   return saved;
}
var myGamePiece;
var myBackground;
var myObstacles = [];
var myScore;
var gameSpeed = 1;

function startGame() {
    myBackground = new component(800, 380,"http://static.giantbomb.com/uploads/original/29/297846/2789895-cool+space+backgrounds+desktop+hd+wallpaper.jpg", 0, 0, "image");
    myGamePiece = new component(50, 50, "http://images.tourismholdings.com/public/2016/02/56bd3c714ecc6.png", 35, 200, "image");
    myScore = new component("30px", "Algerian", "turquoise", 15, 30, "text");
    myGameArea.start();
}

var myGameArea = {
    canvas : document.createElement("canvas"),
    start : function() {
        this.canvas.width = 800;
        this.canvas.height = 290;
        this.context = this.canvas.getContext("2d");
        document.body.insertBefore(this.canvas, document.body.childNodes[0]);
        this.frameNo = 0;
        this.interval = setInterval(updateGameArea, 20);
        },
    clear : function() {
        this.context.clearRect(0, 0, this.canvas.width, this.canvas.height);
    },
    stop : function() {
        clearInterval(this.interval);
    }
}

function component(width, height, color, x, y, type) {
  if (type == "image") {
    this.image = new Image();
    this.image.src = color;
  }
      this.type = type;
    this.width = width;
    this.height = height;
    this.speedX = 0;
    this.speedY = 0; 
    this.gravity = 0.05;
    this.gravitySpeed = 0;
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;   
    this.update = function() {
        ctx = myGameArea.context;
    if (type == "image") {
      ctx.drawImage(this.image, 
        this.x, 
        this.y,
        this.width, this.height);
    }
    else if (this.type == "text") {
      ctx.font = this.width + " " + this.height;
      ctx.fillStyle = color;
      ctx.fillText(this.text, this.x, this.y);
    }
    }
    this.newPos = function() {
        this.gravitySpeed += this.gravity;
        this.x += this.speedX;
        this.y += this.speedY + this.gravitySpeed;
        this.hitBottom();
    }  
     this.hitBottom = function() {
        var rockbottom = myGameArea.canvas.height - this.height;
        if (this.y > rockbottom) {
            this.y = rockbottom;
        }
    }
    this.crashWith = function(otherobj) {
        var myleft = this.x; 
        var myright = this.x + (this.width);
        var mytop = this.y;
        var mybottom = this.y + (this.height);
        var otherleft = otherobj.x;
        var otherright = otherobj.x + (otherobj.width);
        var othertop = otherobj.y;
        var otherbottom = otherobj.y + (otherobj.height);
        var crash = true;
        if ((mybottom < othertop) || (mytop > otherbottom) || (myright < otherleft) || (myleft > otherright)) {
            crash = false;
        }
        return crash;
    }
}

function updateGameArea() {

    var x, height, gap, minHeight, maxHeight, minGap, maxGap;
    for (i = 0; i < myObstacles.length; i += 1) {
        if (myGamePiece.crashWith(myObstacles[i])) {
            myGameArea.stop()
            document.getElementsByClassName("resetButton")[0].innerHTML='<button onclick="location.reload();"<p style="height:27px;width:815px">Restart Game</button>';
            return;
        }
    }
    myGameArea.clear();
    myGameArea.frameNo += 1;
    if (myGameArea.frameNo == 1 || everyinterval(150)) {
        x = myGameArea.canvas.width;
        minHeight = 20;
        maxHeight = 200;
        height = Math.floor(Math.random()*(maxHeight-minHeight+1)+minHeight);
        minGap = 150;
        maxGap = 250;
        gap = Math.floor(Math.random()*(maxGap-minGap+1)+minGap);
        myObstacles.push(new component(15, height, "https://orig00.deviantart.net/bb11/f/2014/127/f/e/hexagon_wallpaper___version_3_by_designedby_jack-d7hh9xo.png", x, 0, "image"));
        myObstacles.push(new component(15, height, "https://orig00.deviantart.net/bb11/f/2014/127/f/e/hexagon_wallpaper___version_3_by_designedby_jack-d7hh9xo.png", x, height + gap, "image"));
        gameSpeed = gameSpeed - 1;    
    }
    myBackground.newPos();   
    myBackground.update();
    for (i = 0; i < myObstacles.length; i += 1) {
        myObstacles[i].x += gameSpeed;
        myObstacles[i].update();
    }
    myScore.text="Space Run                                                         SCORE: " + myGameArea.frameNo;
    myScore.update();
    myGamePiece.newPos();   
    myGamePiece.update();
}

function everyinterval(n) {
    if ((myGameArea.frameNo / n) % 1 == 0) {return true;}
    return false;
}

function moveup() {
    myGamePiece.speedY = -1;
}

function movedown() {
    myGamePiece.speedY = 1;
}

function moveleft() {
    myGamePiece.speedX = -1;
}

function moveright() {
    myGamePiece.speedX = 1;
}

function clearmove() {
    myGamePiece.speedX = 0;
    myGamePiece.speedY = 0;
}
function accelerate(n) {
    myGamePiece.gravity = n;
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
<audio <embed loop="true" autoplay="autoplay">
     <source src="http://a.tumblr.com/tumblr_m545gt2gbp1r5da8vo1.mp3" />     
 </audio>

<script>
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HTML5 canvas how to give it a boundary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15283038/html5-canvas-how-to-give-it-a-boundary)

Comment: Well, that question doesnt give an answer on how to do it, only a code modification for the author of the posted question. It doesnt really help me.